# issues creating a self sizing uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift

In many text input fields such as the one in imessage, once the text reaches the right edge of the field, the field increases its height and wraps the text accordingly. This is the effect I want to achieve in the search bar I am creating however I can't get the resizing to work properly.

Here's what I have so far...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextFieldDelegate {


var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

let searchBarView: UIView = {
    let sbv = UIView()
    sbv.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    sbv.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    return sbv
}()

let searchBar: UITextField = {
    let sBar = UITextField()
    sBar.textAlignment = .left
    sBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return sBar
}()


func setupKeyboardObservers() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func handleKeyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        //print(keyboardFrame as Any)


        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
        let isKeybobardNotShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide


        bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0



        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completed) in


        })







    }

}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}










override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Search Bar"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.searchBar.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(searchBarView)
            searchBarView.addSubview(searchBar)

    setupKeyboardObservers()


    //searchbarview constraints
    searchBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBarView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBarView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.04, constant: 0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBarView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.85, constant: 0).isActive = true


    //searchbar constraints
    searchBarView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-2-[v0]-2-|", views: searchBar)
    searchBarView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-2-[v0]-2-|", views: searchBar)




    bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBarView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint!)



    //Looks for single or multiple taps.
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}






//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentString: String = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    let length: Int = (currentString.characters.count )



    let messageText = currentString
    let size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 0.75, height: self.view.frame.height * 1.25)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)], context: nil)

    if estimatedFrame.width >= self.view.frame.width * 0.745 {

        searchBarView.frame.size.height = estimatedFrame.height
        searchBar.frame.size.height = estimatedFrame.height - 2



        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completed) in

                self.view.addConstraint(self.bottomConstraint!)




        })


    }else{


        NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBarView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBarView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.04, constant: 0).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBarView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.85, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }



    return true
}


}




extension UIView {
func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views : UIView...) {


    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

    for(index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a `UITextView` (multi-line), not `UITextField` (single-line).

Comment: I thought UITextViews couldn't call the keyboard?

Comment: I'll try to implement that but if you run the code, that's not the only problem. I'm having issues with the retaining that bottom constraint after the view resizes.